# Testing component - Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-test-utils

I am trying to write a simple test for my vue component. Since the vue component makes an async call on mount and updates the vuex store, `dispatch` is called during mount, which breaks my existing unit tests. Any idea how to overcome this? Since I am mocking table data, I don't need the mounted() function to be called when running the tests.

MyTable.spec.js

```
     const wrapper = shallowMount(MyTable, {
        propsData: {
            tableData: [
                {
                    "product_id":10826345236,
                    "name":"T-Shirt"
                }
            ],
            columns: ['product_id', 'name'],
            headings: ['Product ID', 'Name'],
            actionType: 'loadProducts'
        }
    });
    ...
```

MyTable.vue

```
    ...
    data() {
        return {
            options: {
                ...
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getHeadings() {
            let headings = {};
            this.columns.map((key, i) => headings[key] = this.headings[i]);
            return headings;
        },
        setColumnClasses() {
            let classes = {};
            this.columns.map((key) => classes[key] = key);
            return classes;
        },
        loadRecords(actionType) {
            this.$store.dispatch(actionType);
        }
    },
    props: {
        tableData: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        columns: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        actionType: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        headings: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        ...
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadRecords(this.actionType);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error message because Vue (when mounted) is expecting that the `this.$store` is defined, and while it might be within your application, you are not importing it, nor are you mocking it.

Here is your test function code you provided:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyTable, {
  propsData: {
    tableData: [
      {
        "product_id":10826345236,
        "name":"T-Shirt"
      }
    ],
    columns: ['product_id', 'name'],
    headings: ['Product ID', 'Name'],
    actionType: 'loadProducts'
  }
});
```

Here is what you need to add:

```
import store from '../path/to/store.js';
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';

// You will want to create a local Vue instance for testing purposes: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#createlocalvue
const localVue = createLocalVue();

// This tells the local Vue instance to use Vuex for the store mechanism.
localVue.use(Vuex);

const wrapper = shallowMount(MyTable, {
  localVue, // Bind the local Vue instance when we shallow-mount the component.
  store, // Bind the store so all of the methods are available when invoked.
  propsData: {
    tableData: [
      {
        "product_id":10826345236,
        "name":"T-Shirt"
      }
    ],
    columns: ['product_id', 'name'],
    headings: ['Product ID', 'Name'],
    actionType: 'loadProducts'
  }
});
```